# Interface for moving messages on mobile chat website

Tags: feature-request, chat, mobile-web

Currently it's not possible to move messages because the mobile chat website doesn't provide that option, and desktop chat on mobile doesn't help because it's not possible to hold a key while selecting a message.

I'd like an interface for moving messages on the mobile chat website. It will greatly help me with moderating the rooms.

Comment: This would greatly help with the moderation effort. There are people, I am sure, who would be available to moderate more, but can't due to not always being at a desktop

Comment: _Needs moar buttons._